# jQuery conditional If height

Tags: jquery

This jquery function works fine, but i want introduce "if". If click again and the height is 40, height = auto

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".admintitle").click(function() {
        $(".1").animate({height:40});
        $('.admintitle').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    });
 });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Click again, as in do the above the first time it is clicked, but do something else on subsequent clicks, if the width is 40px?

Comment: sorry, i modify post. can you see again?

Comment: Class names are more useful when they describe what they're for. "1" is a poor choice for a class name.

Comment: @Blazemonger: And it's even [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)! :-) Vektor: In CSS selectors, class names cannot start with a digit.

Comment: lol, is only for test production. <div class="submenubox 1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation to `auto` height will not work as animation works with only numerical values

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = false;
    $(".admintitle").click(function () {
        if (flag) {
            $(".1").height('auto');
        } else {
            $(".1").animate({
                height: 40
            });
        }
        $('.admintitle').css('background-position', flag ? '0px -20px' :  '0px 0px');
        flag = !flag;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P56Aj/)

Another solution is to use a computed height, if the element has a fixed height

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $1 = $(".1"),
        $title = $(".admintitle"),
        flag = false,
        height = $1.height();
    $title.click(function () {
        $1.animate({
            height: flag ? height : 40
        });
        $('.admintitle').css('background-position', flag ? '0px -20px' :  '0px 0px');
        flag = !flag;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7c3Dy/)

Comment: yeah, this code works! only don't animate like you said. really thanks!

Comment: yeah! really really thanks. in two minutes set answer like accepted!

Comment: only one question more in this code: If i want change background position if height is 40 and auto?

Comment: @vektor to what value? you can use the flag to set it using a condition

Comment: for example, background-position:0px 0px; and background-position:0px -20px;

Comment: I don't know if i must create another post or question here, but, i wish do overflow:hidden or visible

Comment: @vektor see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7c3Dy/2/ ... anyway next item you can ask as a separate question

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(".1").width()` and `$(".1").height()` and compare them with your values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".admintitle").click(function() {
        if ($(".1").width() === 40 && $(".1").height() === 140); {
            $(".1").animate({height:40});
            $('.admintitle').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: sorry, i modify post. can you see again?

Comment: @vektor See [this post about how to check if it's `auto`](http://gregpettit.ca/2012/jquery-check-if-element-has-auto-widthheight/).